# Simple addition not working in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm very new to c# and was trying to make a simple program to add 3 numbers, I'm not sure why it is not working here is the code and the error.

```
int Value;
int Number;
int Thing;

Console.WriteLine("Please State the First Number");
Value = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Please State the Second Number");
Number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Please State the Third Number");
Thing = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("{1}+{2}+{3} = {4}", Value + Number + Thing);

Console.ReadLine();
```

error

> 'ConsoleApp4.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'ConsoleApp4.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'c:\users\cex\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ConsoleApp4\ConsoleApp4\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp4.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>   The program '[13144] ConsoleApp4.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).

Comment: What's the exception message? For one thing you need to provide 4 arguments to `Console.WriteLine` and the format parameters start at 0 instead of 1 e.g. `Console.WriteLine("{0}+{1}+{2} = {3}", Value, Number, Thing, Value + Number + Thing);`.

Comment: When you debug, is there an actual error?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("{1}+{2}+{3} = {4}", Value + Number + Thing);` This is not how it works. Read Console.WriteLine documentation.

Comment: The format string `"{1}+{2}+{3} = {4}"` expects *four* arguments. You only provide one.

Comment: ahh thank you very much, silly me i did know that i just didnt think, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out in the comments `Console.WriteLine` expect four parameters for formatting string, but you provide only one - sum of values `Value + Number + Thing`

With string interpolation you will never face this kind of errors

```
Console.WriteLine($"{Value} + {Number} + {Thing} = {Value + Number + Thing}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this instead:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}+{1}+{2} = {3}", Value, Number, Thing, Value + Number + Thing);
```